# copying data from table to another after adding some changes in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have been struggling to find out how to solve this for the past 2 days.
So here is the setup:

I have a table `movie_rating` with 4 columns, 2 of which I need to copy (id, info (which is a string)).
my new table is `vote_distribution` which has 11 fields (id, mark1, ... mark10), where `mark_i` is calculated using `note` mentioned above.
My table `movie_rating` is full, but `vote_distribution` is empty. What's the best way to do the copying and editing of data using an `update` query?

Here is a sample of the data:

`movie_rating`:

| id | movie_id | info_type_id | info |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 99 | 31.2.1..2. |
| 2 | 1 | 100 | 9 |
| 3 | 1 | 101 | 4.1 |

`vote_distribution`:

| id | mark1 | mark2 | mark3 | mark4 | mark5 | mark6 | mark7 | mark8 | mark9 | mark10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 9 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 4 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

For now I tried:

```
Insert into vote_distribution (id, mark1, mark2, mark3, mark4, mark5, mark6, mark7, mark8, mark9, mark10)

Select id,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10 from
 movie_rating
,(Select CASE
    WHEN SUBSTRING(info,1,1)='' THEN 0
    WHEN SUBSTRING(info,1,1)='.' THEN 0
    WHEN SUBSTRING(info,1,1)='=' THEN 10
WHEN SUBSTRING(info,1,1)='*' THEN -1
    ELSE CAST(SUBSTRING(info,1,1) as integer)
    END as c1
from movie_rating) as m1
 

,(Select CASE
    WHEN SUBSTRING(info,2,1)='' THEN 0
    WHEN SUBSTRING(info,2,1)='.' THEN 0
    WHEN SUBSTRING(info,2,1)='=' THEN 10
WHEN SUBSTRING(info,2,1)='*' THEN -1
    ELSE CAST(SUBSTRING(info,2,1) as integer)
    END  as c2
from movie_rating)as m2


,(Select CASE
    WHEN SUBSTRING(info,3,1)='' THEN 0
    WHEN SUBSTRING(info,3,1)='.' THEN 0
    WHEN SUBSTRING(info,3,1)='=' THEN 10
WHEN SUBSTRING(info,3,1)='*' THEN -1
    ELSE CAST(SUBSTRING(info,3,1) as integer)
    END  as c3
from movie_rating)as m3


,(Select CASE
    WHEN SUBSTRING(info,4,1)='' THEN 0
    WHEN SUBSTRING(info,4,1)='.' THEN 0
    WHEN SUBSTRING(info,4,1)='=' THEN 10
WHEN SUBSTRING(info,4,1)='*' THEN -1
    ELSE CAST(SUBSTRING(info,4,1) as integer)
    END  as c4
from movie_rating)as m4


,(Select CASE
    WHEN SUBSTRING(info,5,1)='' THEN 0
    WHEN SUBSTRING(info,5,1)='.' THEN 0
    WHEN SUBSTRING(info,5,1)='=' THEN 10
WHEN SUBSTRING(info,5,1)='*' THEN -1
    ELSE CAST(SUBSTRING(info,5,1) as integer)
    END  as c5
from movie_rating)as m5


,(Select CASE
    WHEN SUBSTRING(info,6,1)='' THEN 0
    WHEN SUBSTRING(info,6,1)='.' THEN 0
    WHEN SUBSTRING(info,6,1)='=' THEN 10
WHEN SUBSTRING(info,6,1)='*' THEN -1
    ELSE CAST(SUBSTRING(info,6,1) as integer)
    END as c6
from movie_rating)as m6


,(Select CASE
    WHEN SUBSTRING(info,7,1)='' THEN 0
    WHEN SUBSTRING(info,7,1)='.' THEN 0
    WHEN SUBSTRING(info,7,1)='=' THEN 10
WHEN SUBSTRING(info,7,1)='*' THEN -1
    ELSE CAST(SUBSTRING(info,7,1) as integer)
    END as c7
from movie_rating)as m7


,(Select CASE

    WHEN SUBSTRING(info,8,1)='' THEN 0
    WHEN SUBSTRING(info,8,1)='.' THEN 0
    WHEN SUBSTRING(info,8,1)='=' THEN 10
WHEN SUBSTRING(info,8,1)='*' THEN -1
    ELSE CAST(SUBSTRING(info,8,1) as integer)
    END as c8
from movie_rating)as m8

,(Select CASE
    WHEN SUBSTRING(info,9,1)='' THEN 0
    WHEN SUBSTRING(info,9,1)='.' THEN 0
    WHEN SUBSTRING(info,9,1)='=' THEN 10
WHEN SUBSTRING(info,9,1)='*' THEN -1
    ELSE CAST(SUBSTRING(info,9,1) as integer)
    END as c9
from movie_rating)as m9


,(Select CASE
    WHEN SUBSTRING(info,10,1)='' THEN 0
    WHEN SUBSTRING(info,10,1)='.' THEN 0
    WHEN SUBSTRING(info,10,1)='=' THEN 10
WHEN SUBSTRING(info,10,1)='*' THEN -1
    ELSE CAST(SUBSTRING(info,10,1) as integer)
    END as c10
from movie_rating)as m10
```

this probably will work but it takes forever and doesn't seem to end (I ran it for 30 minutes or so).

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Show us some sample table data and also the expected result - all as formatted text (not images, not links.) Simplify! A [mcve].

Comment: @jarlh I am using postgresql, I also am using jdbc to do java commands.

Comment: @jarlh I added the sample data

Comment: Great, also _specify_ the expected result. (Are really 10 mark columns needed to illustrate the problem? Are 3 perhaps enough?)

Comment: @jarlh the "info" string could be anywhere between 1 caracter and 10, so in "vote_distribution" I need it to be 10 marks.

Comment: Why have you got 1 SELECT statement per CASE statement, rather than putting all the CASE statements in a single SELECT statement?

Comment: @NickW oh I dunno, didn't think of that, I'll try that out and see what happens

Comment: How many rows are there in `movie_rating`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT
    id,
    coalesce(ar[1]::int, 0) AS mark1,
    coalesce(ar[2]::int, 0) AS mark2,
    coalesce(ar[3]::int, 0) AS mark3,
    coalesce(ar[4]::int, 0) AS mark4,
    coalesce(ar[5]::int, 0) AS mark5,
    coalesce(ar[6]::int, 0) AS mark6,
    coalesce(ar[7]::int, 0) AS mark7,
    coalesce(ar[8]::int, 0) AS mark8,
    coalesce(ar[9]::int, 0) AS mark9,
    coalesce(ar[10]::int, 0) AS mark10
FROM (
    SELECT
        id,
        array_replace(array_replace(array_replace(regexp_split_to_array(info, ''), '.', '0'), '*', '-1'), '=', '10') ar
    FROM
        movie_rating) AS t;
```